# Find span where condition is True using NumPy

Tags: python, arrays, search, numpy

Imagine I have a numpy array and I need to find the spans/ranges where that condition is True. For example, I have the following array in which I'm trying to find spans where items are greater than 1:

```
[0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0]
```

I would need to find indices (start, stop):

```
(3, 5) 
(6, 9)
```

The fastest thing I've been able to implement is making a boolean array of:

```
truth = data > threshold
```

and then looping through the array using `numpy.argmin` and `numpy.argmax` to find start and end positions.

```
    pos = 0
    truth = container[RATIO,:] > threshold

    while pos < len(truth):
        start = numpy.argmax(truth[pos:]) + pos + offset
        end = numpy.argmin(truth[start:]) + start  + offset
        if not truth[start]:#nothing more
            break
        if start == end:#goes to the end
            end = len(truth)
        pos = end
```

But this has been too slow for the billions of positions in my arrays and the fact that the spans I'm finding are usually just a few positions in a row. Does anyone know a faster way to find these spans?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How's one way. First take the boolean array you have:

```
In [11]: a
Out[11]: array([0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0])

In [12]: a1 = a > 1
```

Shift it one to the left (to get the next state at each index) using [`roll`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html):

```
In [13]: a1_rshifted = np.roll(a1, 1)

In [14]: starts = a1 & ~a1_rshifted  # it's True but the previous isn't

In [15]: ends = ~a1 & a1_rshifted
```

Where this is [non-zero](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html) is the start of each True batch (or, respectively,  end batch):

```
In [16]: np.nonzero(starts)[0], np.nonzero(ends)[0]
Out[16]: (array([3, 6]), array([5, 9]))
```

And zipping these together:

```
In [17]: zip(np.nonzero(starts)[0], np.nonzero(ends)[0])
Out[17]: [(3, 5), (6, 9)]
```

Comment: This looks to be the answer! Running over 7million points took about 20 seconds compared to 50 minutes in the original code. Thanks!

Comment: The edge cases aren't correct because `roll` is being used. For example, if the span should have a start at 0, you will only get that when the last item happens to be `True`.

Comment: @Cuadue that's very True, I have this vague memory of thinking I should correct this at the time, need to somehow update the first and last (?) element after the roll... :s

Comment: I've been hacking on it for an hour myself and haven't found an elegant solution either :X

Comment: (A few years later) Concatenate [False] to the end of a1 immediately after you perform the thresholding. This takes care of the endpoints.

Answer (score 3):

If you have access to the scipy library:

You can use [scipy.ndimage.measurements.label](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.measurements.label.html#scipy.ndimage.measurements.label) to identify any regions of non zero value. it returns an array where the value of each element is the id of a span or range in the original array.

You can then use [scipy.ndimage.measurements.find_objects](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.measurements.find_objects.html#scipy.ndimage.measurements.find_objects) to return the slices you would need to extract those ranges. You can access the start / end values directly from those slices.

In your example:

```
import numpy
from scipy.ndimage.measurements import label, find_objects

data = numpy.array([0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0])

labels, number_of_regions = label(data)
ranges = find_objects(labels)

for identified_range in ranges:
    print(identified_range[0].start, identified_range[0].stop)
```

You should see:

```
3 5
6 9
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Just an update on performance - for what it's worth! This performs 7 million points in ~0.6 seconds on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using np.roll which has a serious problem that it rolls. You're better off just making two copies. One with right-pad and the other with left-pad. I needed this for an image.

```py
        a = np.pad(im, ((0, 0), (0, 1)), constant_values=0)
        b = np.pad(im, ((0, 0), (1, 0)), constant_values=0)
        starts = a & ~b
        ends = ~a & b
        sx, sy = np.nonzero(starts)
        ex, ey = np.nonzero(ends)
```

The approved answer has a problem, in that, if you end with True, that gets rolled to the front and messes up the values. You really want to pad these values with 0.

Then you're finding 1 -> 0 transitions and the 0 -> 1 transitions and putting those in your needed format.